# codeigniter pagination not working category get the page post

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

controller:
category get post data. but how to set up
view:
view page its working.but when again click second page its not workin

i tried argument->$offset=0

```
public function posts($id){
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'posts/category/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('posts');
    $config['per_page'] = 4;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'pagination-link');
    // Initialize
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['title'] = $this->category_model->get_category($id)->name;
    $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_posts_by_category($config['per_page'], $id);

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/category', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Comment: offser? Do you mean offset?

Comment: $offset=0   correct

Comment: when i click next page the error is -> 404 Page Not Found

Comment: i have more post under the category, but here get only two post. i want more post using pagination

Answer (score 2):

You said it shows `404` and that means it's been redirected to a wrong url and cannot reach your controller and that doesn't depend on your retrieved data from your model at all.

Maybe there is something wrong with your `base_url`, so make sure it is being redirected to `BASE_URL/posts/category/NUMBER`.

And about your other pagination configs, it's all fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $config = array();
 $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "posts/category";
  $config["total_rows"] = $this->post_model->record_count();
   $config["per_page"] = 4;
   $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
   $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
  $data["results"] = $this->post_model->
  get_posts_by_category($config["per_page"], $page);
  $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
  $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/category', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Post_model::record_count()

Comment: which method you are using to get all data from table use this record_count for that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way it can help you,
In Controller:

```
$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/pagination_controller/contact_info";
$total_row = $this->pagination_model->record_count();
$config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
$config["per_page"] = 1;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['num_links'] = $total_row;
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
$config['next_link'] = 'Next';
$config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
if($this->uri->segment(3)){
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
}
else{
$page = 1;
}
$data["results"] = $this->pagination_model->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);
$str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
$data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );

// View data according to array.
$this->load->view("pagination_view", $data);
```

Here replace pagination_model with your model.

Now in your view file just loop it through links:

```
<div id="pagination">
<ul class="tsc_pagination">

<!-- Show pagination links -->
<?php foreach ($links as $link) {
echo "<li>". $link."</li>";
} ?>
</ul>
</div>
```